# Completely Changing JLabel on command

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

What I'm trying to do is have an image set as a label. My problem is when I go to change the image through a confirmation button, nothing happens.

I'm using `NetBeans` `JFrame` Designer or whatever, but here is what its doing..

Default, I have the `JLabel` set as normal no changes or anything. basically I made it and removed the text, so its empty. Now when the user clicks a button, I want an image to come up, as they choose. Basically I'm trying to change the color of an image, that they choose it to go to.

```
frontDesign = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Functions.getShirt("front")));
```

This is what I'm using to change it. basically I'm resetting the `JLabel`, which isn't doing anything.. Is there another solution, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've tried to set all the variables it sets defaultly, in the same method, but its not doing anything with that either,

Comment: Don't add a comment. Update your question. All the relevant information to the question should be in one place.

Comment: You're confusing a variable with an object. Yes you're changing and updating the frontDesign **variable**, but this has no effect on the JLabel **object** that it previously referred to and that is showing in your GUI. Understand that variables are only references to objects, and it is the underlying object here that is much more important and that whose state you need to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a new label. Changing the reference of a variable does not add the label to the GUI. The newly created label is just sitting in memory doing nothing.

Just use:

```
frontDesign.setIcon(...);
```

This will replace the icon off the label currently displayed on the frame.